# JQuery Autocomplete from DB

Tags: jquery, grails, autocomplete

I'm implementing autocomplete into the majority of the fields I have in my forms for my grails application.

Currently I have this code (below) that allows me to manually input values that will be suggested to the user as they type, in this example I've filled in two autocomplete values for two fields:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function() {

 $( "#parameterName" ).autocomplete({
   source: ["HelloHi", "Moose"]
 });
 $( "#defaultValue" ).autocomplete({
   source: ["Blah", "Bleh"]
 });
});
```

The question I have is, what do I need to change so that instead of me having to manually enter values, I can simply get it to retrieve all of the values from a column in a database and use those to auto-suggest/complete?

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

The function I have in the form.gsp:

```
<script>
$(function() {

$( "#parameterName" ).autocomplete({
  source: '${g.createLink(controller: 'templateInput', action: 'suggestedParameterNames')}'
  });
 });
</script>
```

The function I have in my controller for templateInput:

```
def suggestedParameterNames() {
    def suggestions = templatingService.getSuggestedParamNameValues()

    render suggestions as JSON
}
```

The function I have in my service:

```
def getSuggestedParamNameValues(){
    def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    def row = sql.rows("select distinct parameter_name from template_input")

    return row
}
```

The problem I now have is that when I type into the field it returns EVERY value in the column. I want it so that if I type in the word 'card' it only suggests the values starting with the word 'card'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The [autocomplete plugin docs](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) include the following example

Html:

```
<input type="text" name="country" id="autocomplete"/>
```

Ajax lookup:

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '/autocomplete/countries',
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    }
});
```

In your case, rather than hard-coding the URL that returns the list of suggestions you should use the `g.createLink` tag, e.g.

```
serviceUrl: '${g.createLink(controller: "autocomplete", action: "countries")}',
```

Comment: I think the question is about the jQuery UI autocomplete widget http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete and not the autocomplete plugin.